# Implementing a login screen with tabs

Tags: android, authentication, tabs, logout, remember-me

I am working on an application which requires me to create a log in screen. The way I have planned to do this is have 2 tabs log in, sign up and what I wanted to know is I want to be able to have a user sign up and if they choose remember password next time they load the app it should go straight to the main menu. Although selecting sign out in the main menu should load up the tabs with the log in information when they start the app again.

The question I have is how do I implement the remember me button so next time it skips the log in and how do I implement the sign out so next time the app loads the log in screen.

Thank you in advance! (",)

Sri

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT (all caps = shouting). I've fixed your title for you so it doesn't shout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Log In :

```
SharedPreferences sSession = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor ePrefrences = sSession.edit();
ePrefrences.putString("id", "user id"); 
ePrefrences.putString("password", "user password");
ePrefrences.putBoolean("successfullylogin", true);
ePrefrences.commit();
```

Second Log In :

```
SharedPreferences sSession = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if (sSession .getBoolean("successfullylogin", false)) {
//get user name and password
sUser = sSession.getString("id", "");
sPassword = sSession.getString("password", "");
//start activity
} 
else {
//prepare for normal login 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example you have provided me with I really appreciate it, but the problem is if I was to use preference  would I be able to check the saved preferences Eg Login detail with the database?
As well as wouldn’t it be better to use a database SQLlite to store the registration and retrieve the login information from the database. Following this could I then use preferences to store the login information to check with the database.  Hope you understand what i am trying to say.
Thanks in advance (",)

Sri

Answer (score 3):

Throw the remembered answer into the `SharedPreferences` and read it when your activity starts and process it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) to store the username/password for the remember me button. 
When the app loads, first check if the user/pass is already saved. If so then direct to the tabs, if not then direct to the log in screen.

Comment: I think `SharedPreferences` is a better method, since that allows you to store key:value pairs. See @JoxTraex and @Basbous answers.